# Basement HVAC supply location

Tags: hvac, basement

I'm finishing my basement and I'm wondering how I should approach placement of the supply vents. I live in Minnesota so my primary consideration is to do what I can to make sure the space can be kept comfortably warm in the winter. From the research I've done, it sounds like ideally they should go near the windows and low. At the same time, I don't want to take a more difficult route if it's unlikely to have any noticeable benefit over an easier one. I figure I generally have 3 options in order of least to most effort:

1. Place the supply vents on the ceiling near the windows/exterior walls with returns on opposing   walls and placed low.
2. Place supply vents low on the walls adjacent to the exterior walls as close to the windows as possible.
3. Place the supply vents low on the exterior walls a couple of stud bays from the windows. I would have to cut the existing vapor barrier and remove some insulation to make room for the duct work.

My assumption is that 3 isn't a good route to take. But I'm unsure of whether placing the supply vents low on the walls will be enough of an improvement over having them in the ceilings to make it worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is do the most effective of the available option for each room. You may not get them all set up exactly the same.

For most modern basements in Minnesota the supplies are in the ceiling near the windows and the returns are low on an opposing wall. That's the ideal, in my opinion. You get better flow over and around the window with this arrangement since the air can be directed downward, along the window. It's difficult to do that from a wall vent, so condensation and frost build up more readily, and the air near the windows feels colder (and therefore more drafty).

Obviously it's difficult to get a vent below a window on an exterior wall, and you wouldn't want to compromise your insulation and HVAC air temp by doing so anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense as far as the ceiling being the most effective place to get the air going over the windows. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

@isherwood offers some good advice. Also, I have finished my basement so let me give you some advice. If the sq ft area of the basement is the same as the floor above you will need to add almost as many supply registers and returns depending on the amount of wall insulation and/or the amount of walls that are below grade. Adding 1 or 2 supplies and returns will not be enough. If you put the supply registers in the ceiling use registers that can direct the discharge air directly to the floor and can be closed in the summer if you have A/C. The returns should be near the floor. Not putting in enough supply and return registers will be a huge mistake. I have redone mine 3 times just trying to get the basement warm enough in the winter.

I insulated the walls with R19 and still have trouble getting the basement warm enough even though I have 7 hot air supplies and 4 return air grills.